# How to open offcanvas from offcanvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a little problem with open one offcanvas from previous canvas. Generally I have canvas like this using bootstrap 5:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasBottom" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom">Toggle bottom offcanvas</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasBottom" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasBottomLabel">Offcanvas bottom</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body small">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#secondoffcanvas" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">Open second offcanvas</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

second offcanvas:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom" tabindex="-1" id="secondoffcanvas" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasBottomLabel">Offcanvas bottom</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body small">
    second content
  </div>
</div>
```

My scenario:

1. Click to open first offcanvas
2. Click on the button in canvas
   Resulst:

- first canvas hide
- second canvas open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read "[how it works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#how-it-works)"...

> "Similar to modals, only one offcanvas can be shown at a time."

However, you can open one from the other. Programmatically show the 2nd when the 1st is hidden...

```
var offcanvasBottom = document.getElementById('offcanvasBottom')
var secondoffcanvas = document.getElementById('secondoffcanvas')

offcanvasBottom.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function () {
  var bsOffcanvas2 = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(secondoffcanvas)
  bsOffcanvas2.show()
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/bRG1F8mtQk)

Comment: Yes, I know it. But can't keep in mind how resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks You #Zim. This resolve my issue. I have one question jet. What You think about identify if event was triggered from button on the offcanvas and no triggered from other place? Because now if You click in othe place second canvas is open too

Comment: @pufo I actually used this answer but put the trigger on the button. It worked and I was able to solve the issue which you talked about in your comment. If you want / I have time, I will write my solution as an answer. Let me know!

Comment: That's odd. I've not had an issues showing multiple `offcanvas` items at once. Same side. Different Sides. They can only be dismissed in reverse order unless you use JS to do something else. I use JS to load their content and show them - I don't use the attribute method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks You #Zim. This resolve my issue. I have one question jet. What You think about identify if event was triggered from button on the offcanvas and no triggered from other place? Because now if You click in othe place second canvas is open too

Comment: Comment on my answer.. don't add a new answer

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue when I show the project detail information, try this code will solve your issue:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Multi-level Offcanvas Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="firstOffcanvas">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title">Project history</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <p>project histories</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="openSecondOffcanvas">Project Detail</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="secondOffcanvas">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title">Project Detail</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <p>This is the project detail.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#firstOffcanvas">Open Project Histories</button>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        let openSecondOffcanvasButton = document.getElementById('openSecondOffcanvas');
        openSecondOffcanvasButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            let firstOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(document.getElementById('firstOffcanvas'));
            let secondOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(document.getElementById('secondOffcanvas'));

            firstOffcanvas.hide();
            secondOffcanvas.show();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function toggle() {
    document.getElementById('offcanvas').classList.toggle('show');
}
```